# Python odeint: overwriting a variable in a running solver

Tags: python, math, scipy, differential-equations

I admit, the question sounds strange.
I've created a system of 11 ODEs in which the first equation resembles a exponentially declining out-of-system signal.

```
dx1/dt = -v1*x1
```

In real system this signal originates from some kind of glitch the best case scenario is `x1 = 0 = const`. , therefore, but I'm interested in what this does to my system, so I need to chance `x1 = 0` to `x = 1` at certain points. `dx1/dt = -v1*x1` resets x1 to near 0 afterwards (I don't think any x1 below 0.01 affects the overall system).

For example: Lets say the signal appears at `t = (5,7,13,17)`. so with v1 = 0.5 x1 would be

```
x1 = (0,0,0,0,0,1,0.5,1,0.5,0.25,0.125,0.0625,0.03125, 0.015626,~0,~0,~0,1)
```

I'm not sure how to model this behaviour my first guess was to just overwrite the x1 values if the solver hits my tresholds but apparently this isn't as easy as it sounds...

Ideas anyone?

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you are asking; e.g. what means "the signal appears", which integrator are you using (odeint?)? It would also be helpful to see the system of ODEs.

Comment: It's not really a problem with the solver or the other equations. I need to know how I can insert this weird behaviour were `x(t) = 0` most of the time but at some points `t = 5` for example `x(t)` jumps to  `x(t) = 1` and would just stay this way if `v1 = 0` in `dx1/dt = -v1*x1`. My initial value is `x(0) = 0` and I neet to overwrite the `x(t)` values for some `t`. A partial integration like one would use for a stepwise function would probably yield the same result as desired but this seems to be a lot of efford which I hope is avoid able.

Comment: You could have a look at [PyDSTool](http://www.ni.gsu.edu/~rclewley/PyDSTool/FrontPage.html) which is able to handle events. For more help, one really needs to know your equations...